# column sort in a multidiminsional array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Is this the correct way to sort a m by n matrix according to it's columns? thanks. Would a selection sort be best for this?

sorted is an array of mxn double values

```
 for (int j = 0; j < sorted[0].length; j++)
  {

     for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) 
     {

        double currentMin = sorted[i][j];
        int minIndex = i;

        for (int row = i + 1; row < sorted.length; row++)
        {

           if (currentMin > sorted[row][j]) 
           {
              currentMin = sorted[row][j];
              minIndex = row;
           }
        }
        if (minIndex != i) 
        {
           sorted[minIndex][j] = sorted[i][j];
           sorted[i][j] = currentMin;
        }

     }
  }
  return sorted;
```

}

Comment: This is a selection sort, not a bubble sort. A selection sort *selects* the next value from the values not yet sorted and then swaps it with whatever is in the target location (one swap for each element). In a bubble sort, the value swaps with each element between its current location and target location (up to n swaps for each element). Your code selection sorts each column of the 2D array in increasing order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I numbered the code so that I can easily reference parts of it in my description.

```
1. for (int j = 0; j < sorted[0].length; j++)
  {

2.     for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) 
     {

3.        double currentMin = sorted[i][j];
3.        int minIndex = i;

4.        for (int row = i + 1; row < sorted.length; row++)
        {

5.           if (currentMin > sorted[row][j]) 
           {
              currentMin = sorted[row][j];
              minIndex = row;
           }
        }
6.        if (minIndex != i) 
        {
           sorted[minIndex][j] = sorted[i][j];
           sorted[i][j] = currentMin;
        }

     }
  }
  return sorted;
}
```

1. Iterates through all of the columns
2. Iterates through all of the rows
3. Sets up the current minimum and minimum index to the first item being checked. This is just in case they are the actual minimum. Also, we have something to check against as we move forward.
4. Iterate through all the rows beginning with the rows that have not yet been sorted.
5. If the current minimum is greater than the current column and row being incremented (only incrementing the row here) by #4 then set the current minimum and minimum index accordingly
6. This is after all the rows have been checked for the lowest value. If the minimum index is not i (the value we set at step #3) then change it accordingly. Put the minimum value at the index of step #3 and put the value in step #3 at the location where the minimum index was found (a flip flop)

Steps 1 and 2 make sure every value is checked.
Steps 4 - 6 find the minimum and put it in the right place. Only one value is moved in each iteration of these steps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see it now.

Comment: @user3358116 So, please, click in the arrow to upvote my answer, and then click in the V to accept it :)